# Use variable in replace filter?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Is it possible to use a variable value as the text to replace in a jinja2 replace filter?

For example, if I have the variables

`test_file_home: /home/test`

`test_file_path: /home/test/results/test_results.txt`

I'd like to remove the "/home/test" portion of test_file_path by using the test_file_home variable.  The test_file_home and test_file_path values can vary, hence why they are variables and not something I can hard-code.

I'd like to end up with /results/test_results.txt

In my template I was trying something like

`test_file_path |replace({{ test_file_home }},'')`

But no luck.

Comment: [Moustaches don't stack](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the variable without creating a new jinja expression via `{{` and `}}`. Nested jinja expressions are not possible and not required.

`{{ test_file_path | replace(test_file_home, '') }}`

---

Example Task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ test_file_path | replace(test_file_home, '') }}"
  vars:
    test_file_home: /home/test
    test_file_path: /home/test/results/test_results.txt
```

Result:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "/results/test_results.txt"
}
```